# Go the following Gradle issue

Tags: android, gradle, android-jetpack-compose

My Android Studio gives the following error. I used various Kotlin and Compose versions, and it all seems to be the same. The error happens each time. I tried using versions 1.4.6, 1.5.0, and 1.5.1, but none of those worked; the issue persists. I also invalidated my cache and cleared any cache in Android Studio, but the problem remains unchanged.

```
 Task :app:compileDebugKotlin FAILED
    e: java.lang.Error: Something went wrong while checking for version compatibility between the Compose Compiler and the Kotlin Compiler.  It is possible that the versions are incompatible.  Please verify your kotlin version  and consult the Compose-Kotlin compatibility map located at https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose-kotlin
        at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.ComposeComponentRegistrar$Companion.checkCompilerVersion(ComposePlugin.kt:274)
        at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.ComposeComponentRegistrar.registerProjectComponents(ComposePlugin.kt:199)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinCoreEnvironment$Companion.registerExtensionsFromPlugins$cli(KotlinCoreEnvironment.kt:656)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinCoreEnvironment$ProjectEnvironment.registerExtensionsFromPlugins(KotlinCoreEnvironment.kt:169)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinCoreEnvironment$Companion.configureProjectEnvironment(KotlinCoreEnvironment.kt:566)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinCoreEnvironment.<init>(KotlinCoreEnvironment.kt:199)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinCoreEnvironment.<init>(KotlinCoreEnvironment.kt:108)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinCoreEnvironment$Companion.createForProduction(KotlinCoreEnvironment.kt:445)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.createCoreEnvironment(K2JVMCompiler.kt:192)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:143)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:53)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.kt:99)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.kt:47)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLITool.exec(CLITool.kt:101)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.runCompiler(IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.kt:475)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.runCompiler(IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.kt:125)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.compileIncrementally(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:373)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.compileIncrementally$default(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:318)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.rebuild(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:114)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.compileImpl(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:207)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.compile(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:79)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImplBase.execIncrementalCompiler(CompileServiceImpl.kt:625)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImplBase.access$execIncrementalCompiler(CompileServiceImpl.kt:101)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.compile(CompileServiceImpl.kt:1746)
        at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor102.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(Unknown Source)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Unknown Source)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Unknown Source)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(Unknown Source)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(Unknown Source)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Unknown Source)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
    Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'void org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.messages.MessageCollector.report$default(org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.messages.MessageCollector, org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.messages.CompilerMessageSeverity, java.lang.String, org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.messages.CompilerMessageSourceLocation, int, java.lang.Object)'
        at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.ComposeComponentRegistrar$Companion.checkCompilerVersion(ComposePlugin.kt:252)
        ... 39 more
    
    
    java.lang.Error: Something went wrong while checking for version compatibility between the Compose Compiler and the Kotlin Compiler.  It is possible that the versions are incompatible.  Please verify your kotlin version  and consult the Compose-Kotlin compatibility map located at https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose-kotlin
        at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.ComposeComponentRegistrar$Companion.checkCompilerVersion(ComposePlugin.kt:274)
        at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.ComposeComponentRegistrar.registerProjectComponents(ComposePlugin.kt:199)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinCoreEnvironment$Companion.registerExtensionsFromPlugins$cli(KotlinCoreEnvironment.kt:656)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinCoreEnvironment$ProjectEnvironment.registerExtensionsFromPlugins(KotlinCoreEnvironment.kt:169)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinCoreEnvironment$Companion.configureProjectEnvironment(KotlinCoreEnvironment.kt:566)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinCoreEnvironment.<init>(KotlinCoreEnvironment.kt:199)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinCoreEnvironment.<init>(KotlinCoreEnvironment.kt:108)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinCoreEnvironment$Companion.createForProduction(KotlinCoreEnvironment.kt:445)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.createCoreEnvironment(K2JVMCompiler.kt:192)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:143)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:53)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.kt:99)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.kt:47)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLITool.exec(CLITool.kt:101)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.runCompiler(IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.kt:475)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.runCompiler(IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.kt:125)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.compileIncrementally(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:373)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.compileIncrementally$default(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:318)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.rebuild(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:114)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.compileImpl(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:207)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.compile(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:79)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImplBase.execIncrementalCompiler(CompileServiceImpl.kt:625)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImplBase.access$execIncrementalCompiler(CompileServiceImpl.kt:101)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.compile(CompileServiceImpl.kt:1746)
        at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor102.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(Unknown Source)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Unknown Source)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Unknown Source)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(Unknown Source)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(Unknown Source)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Unknown Source)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
    Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'void org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.messages.MessageCollector.report$default(org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.messages.MessageCollector, org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.messages.CompilerMessageSeverity, java.lang.String, org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.messages.CompilerMessageSourceLocation, int, java.lang.Object)'
        at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.ComposeComponentRegistrar$Companion.checkCompilerVersion(ComposePlugin.kt:252)
        ... 39 more
    
    
    
    Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugKotlin'.
    > A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.GradleCompilerRunnerWithWorkers$GradleKotlinCompilerWorkAction
       > Internal compiler error. See log for more details
    
    * Try:
    > Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
    > Run with --scan to get full insights.
    > Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.
    
    * Exception is:
    org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugKotlin'.
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.lambda$executeIfValid$1(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:149)
        at org.gradle.internal.Try$Failure.ifSuccessfulOrElse(Try.java:282)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeIfValid(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:147)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:135)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:46)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.java:51)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:57)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:74)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:36)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.executeTask(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:77)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:55)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:204)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:199)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:53)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:73)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
        at org.gradle.execution.plan.LocalTaskNodeExecutor.execute(LocalTaskNodeExecutor.java:42)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:337)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:324)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:317)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:303)
        at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:463)
        at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:380)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.AbstractManagedExecutor$1.run(AbstractManagedExecutor.java:47)
    Caused by: org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerExecutor$WorkExecutionException: A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.GradleCompilerRunnerWithWorkers$GradleKotlinCompilerWorkAction
        at org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerExecutor$WorkItemExecution.waitForCompletion(DefaultWorkerExecutor.java:283)
        at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultAsyncWorkTracker.lambda$waitForItemsAndGatherFailures$2(DefaultAsyncWorkTracker.java:130)
        at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:31)
        at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withoutLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:321)
        at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withoutLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:304)
        at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withoutLock(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:309)
        at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultAsyncWorkTracker.waitForItemsAndGatherFailures(DefaultAsyncWorkTracker.java:126)
        at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultAsyncWorkTracker.waitForItemsAndGatherFailures(DefaultAsyncWorkTracker.java:92)
        at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultAsyncWorkTracker.waitForAll(DefaultAsyncWorkTracker.java:78)
        at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultAsyncWorkTracker.waitForCompletion(DefaultAsyncWorkTracker.java:66)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution$3.run(TaskExecution.java:256)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:29)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:26)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.run(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:47)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:68)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution.executeAction(TaskExecution.java:233)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution.executeActions(TaskExecution.java:216)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution.executeWithPreviousOutputFiles(TaskExecution.java:199)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution.execute(TaskExecution.java:166)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.executeInternal(ExecuteStep.java:105)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.access$000(ExecuteStep.java:44)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep$1.call(ExecuteStep.java:59)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep$1.call(ExecuteStep.java:56)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:204)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:199)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:53)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:73)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.execute(ExecuteStep.java:56)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.execute(ExecuteStep.java:44)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RemovePreviousOutputsStep.execute(RemovePreviousOutputsStep.java:67)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RemovePreviousOutputsStep.execute(RemovePreviousOutputsStep.java:37)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CancelExecutionStep.execute(CancelExecutionStep.java:41)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.TimeoutStep.executeWithoutTimeout(TimeoutStep.java:74)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.TimeoutStep.execute(TimeoutStep.java:55)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CreateOutputsStep.execute(CreateOutputsStep.java:50)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CreateOutputsStep.execute(CreateOutputsStep.java:28)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateAfterExecutionStep.executeDelegateBroadcastingChanges(CaptureStateAfterExecutionStep.java:100)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateAfterExecutionStep.execute(CaptureStateAfterExecutionStep.java:72)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateAfterExecutionStep.execute(CaptureStateAfterExecutionStep.java:50)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveInputChangesStep.execute(ResolveInputChangesStep.java:40)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveInputChangesStep.execute(ResolveInputChangesStep.java:29)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BuildCacheStep.executeWithoutCache(BuildCacheStep.java:179)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BuildCacheStep.lambda$execute$1(BuildCacheStep.java:70)
        at org.gradle.internal.Either$Right.fold(Either.java:175)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.caching.CachingState.fold(CachingState.java:59)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BuildCacheStep.execute(BuildCacheStep.java:68)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BuildCacheStep.execute(BuildCacheStep.java:46)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.StoreExecutionStateStep.execute(StoreExecutionStateStep.java:36)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.StoreExecutionStateStep.execute(StoreExecutionStateStep.java:25)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RecordOutputsStep.execute(RecordOutputsStep.java:36)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RecordOutputsStep.execute(RecordOutputsStep.java:22)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.executeBecause(SkipUpToDateStep.java:91)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.lambda$execute$2(SkipUpToDateStep.java:55)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.execute(SkipUpToDateStep.java:55)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.execute(SkipUpToDateStep.java:37)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveChangesStep.execute(ResolveChangesStep.java:65)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveChangesStep.execute(ResolveChangesStep.java:36)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.java:37)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.java:27)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveCachingStateStep.execute(ResolveCachingStateStep.java:77)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveCachingStateStep.execute(ResolveCachingStateStep.java:38)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ValidateStep.execute(ValidateStep.java:94)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ValidateStep.execute(ValidateStep.java:49)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.execute(CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.java:71)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.execute(CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.java:45)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipEmptyWorkStep.executeWithNonEmptySources(SkipEmptyWorkStep.java:177)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipEmptyWorkStep.execute(SkipEmptyWorkStep.java:86)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipEmptyWorkStep.execute(SkipEmptyWorkStep.java:53)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RemoveUntrackedExecutionStateStep.execute(RemoveUntrackedExecutionStateStep.java:32)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RemoveUntrackedExecutionStateStep.execute(RemoveUntrackedExecutionStateStep.java:21)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsStartedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsStartedStep.java:38)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.LoadPreviousExecutionStateStep.execute(LoadPreviousExecutionStateStep.java:36)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.LoadPreviousExecutionStateStep.execute(LoadPreviousExecutionStateStep.java:23)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CleanupStaleOutputsStep.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsStep.java:75)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CleanupStaleOutputsStep.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsStep.java:41)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.AssignWorkspaceStep.lambda$execute$0(AssignWorkspaceStep.java:32)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution$4.withWorkspace(TaskExecution.java:293)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.AssignWorkspaceStep.execute(AssignWorkspaceStep.java:30)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.AssignWorkspaceStep.execute(AssignWorkspaceStep.java:21)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.IdentityCacheStep.execute(IdentityCacheStep.java:37)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.IdentityCacheStep.execute(IdentityCacheStep.java:27)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.IdentifyStep.execute(IdentifyStep.java:47)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.IdentifyStep.execute(IdentifyStep.java:34)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.DefaultExecutionEngine$1.execute(DefaultExecutionEngine.java:64)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeIfValid(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:146)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:135)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:46)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.java:51)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:57)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:74)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:36)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.executeTask(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:77)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:55)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
        at

    
    
    BUILD FAILED in 678ms
    27 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 26 up-to-date
```

Here is my gradle:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
}

android {
    namespace 'com.smartjot.smartjot'
    compileSdk 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.smartjot.smartjot"
        minSdk 26
        targetSdk 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary true
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '17'
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose true
    }
    composeOptions {

        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion '1.4.6'
    }
    packagingOptions {
        resources {
            excludes += '/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.10.1'
    implementation platform('org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-bom:1.8.0')
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.6.1'
    implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.7.2'
    implementation platform('androidx.compose:compose-bom:2022.10.00')
    implementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui'
    implementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-graphics'
    implementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview'
    implementation 'androidx.compose.material3:material3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth-ktx:22.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
    androidTestImplementation platform('androidx.compose:compose-bom:2022.10.00')
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4'
    debugImplementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling'
    debugImplementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-manifest'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to replace

```
 compileOptions {
     sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
     targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
 }
```

with

```
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The BOM compose version you are using is incompatible with the kotlin version as the error suggests, check https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose-kotlin for compatible kotlin and compose versions.

Also check https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/bom/bom-mapping to see the versions your BOM compose is using to know if the match.

Having a look, your compose version is actually `1.3.0` which should work with kotlin `1.7.10`. downgrading kotlin to `1.7.10` or upgrading compose BOM to `2023.03.00` should fix the error